# Find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\lfloor \sin x\rfloor}{\lfloor x\rfloor}$

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am unable to evaluate this limit. The floor function is giving me trouble.
Any help will be appreciated. And please edit it so that it looks readable.

Comment: The limit does not exist, for technical reasons: for small positive $x$, evaluating our function involves division by $0$.

Comment: What is $\lfloor 0.9999999\rfloor$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $0<x<1$ we have $\lfloor x\rfloor=0$ so the fraction isn't defined so we can only look for the left limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\lfloor \sin x\rfloor}{\lfloor x\rfloor}=\frac{-1}{-1}=1$$